# Unity3d app immediately goes to background after starting up on iOS

Tags: unity, ios

So the iOS build of my game started doing this today and I have no idea why. The only think I can think of is that I added this line :

```
Application.runInBackground = true;
```

but this should not force it to go to the background on startup. Other games run just fine on the phone. It's very unlikely that the game itself is using too much resources. It does not crash it just goes into the background and when you select it from there it stays on for like a second and then goes back. Has anyone experienced this before ?

Comment: Does removing that line solve the problem?

Comment: As soon as the damn Mac stop updating and I can build i will try this.